# Define compilation flags (C++11 and optimization) via macro

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I want for my program to use C++11 standard and O3 optimization.
Normally I would just use compilation flags: `-std=c++11` and `-O3`, but I have to send sourcefile to a remote server where it is compiled automatically. So basically the only thing that comes to my mind is to use some neat  macro. I am pretty sure it is possible to define optimization that way cause I saw it somewhere, but still I cannot remember how it looked like.

Comment: The problem you're dealing with is not a technical one, but a social one. If the remote server administrator doesn't want to let you specify command-line options, you shouldn't be trying to specify command-line options. If the remote server administrator does want to let you specify command-line options, you'll be able to work out some interface for specifying them that works well for both of you.

Comment: I've talked to the server administrator and he said he cannot change command-line options but if I could somehow enforce it via macro(s), then it would be ok.

Comment: @user3340553 At this point I think it might be beneficial if you could provide us with more information about the service. Maybe we can suggest a replacement, since this one appears “broken”. Then again, without knowing more, we can’t say. Maybe this is for a contest and the rules (arbitrarily) restrict compiler settings?

Comment: @user3340553 Or perhaps, this is an interface used by others as well, and it's tricky to modify the existing interface to allow specifying command-line options? In that case, would the server administrator be willing to set up a new interface that does allow it (without affecting the old interface)?

Comment: @KonradRudolph This is for my advanced course Algorithms and Data structures. Basically it works like that I have a problem to solve similar to most programming competitions. After writing the program I have to send sourcefile via website. Then it is tested if it works correctly or not and if it works in specified time and memory. I have asked specifically lecturer of this course if I can do that and the answer was positive.

Comment: @user3340553 Ah, that makes it tricky. I would say that the best course is: politely (!) ask them to use C++11 as the default compile option. You can reasonably argue that this is a change that *should* be made since C++11 is the most current C++ standard, is implemented completely by almost all modern compilers and brings much-needed improvements to the language. You could even phrase this as a “bug report” / “feature request” to the server administrator, since it’s definitely an objective deficiency that should be addressed by them.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yeah, probably it would be the best way to resolve issue, although I am not sure if it'll work out, since server administrator is actually my lecturer and I've already talked about it. But I suppose it won't hurt to try again. Sadly C++11 is implemented in g++,but it's not enabled by default :(

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking for is outside the C++ spec.

So if it were supported at all--anywhere--it would be supported via pragmas.  I don't know of any pragma to say "compile as C++11", so I'd call that a lost cause.  There do seem to be some optimization pragmas out there:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html

But bear in mind that using a #pragma is entirely outside of the spec.  If the compiler hits one, it can do anything it likes and still be standard.  That includes launching video games *[(and this has been done)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#Compiler_easter_eggs)*

So long story short: if this is a requirement for you, then you need to tell whoever this is providing your compilation service that you need certain compiler settings for your program.

Comment: And more importantly (as I found out at work the other day), -Wpragmas + -Werror makes this give an error.

Comment: @KonradRudolph In a tag (not always super explicit), and your point is...?  If you know the "compile as C++11" pragma in gcc I'll grant I learned something new from the answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph and what's the problem?

Comment: @bolov No problem. But the answer makes rather a big point out of the fact that what OP’s asking is outside the C++ standard. Only, OP seems perfectly aware of that. And, HostileFork, that’s what tags are for (never mind that the title also said it before I changed it).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't see demonstrable "this is not in the spec" knowledge, and *"the only thing that comes to my mind is to use some neat macro"* would seem to support that idea, and until you can show me an in-band GCC setting for compiling as C++11 I think my answer with the function optimization pragmas is ok.

Comment: @HostileFork You seem to completely over-interpret my comment. Your answer is totally fine, and probably as good as it gets. I just wanted to point out that your repeated mention that this isn’t standard is probably barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Re:  *(and this has been done)* Have a link, please? :)

Comment: @jrok Not exactly Tetris, but [here's something very similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#Compiler_easter_eggs) :)

Comment: @jrok I may have misremembered the launched game.  Call me lazy for not feeling like researching the link.  Thanks to lazyweb, updated with the reference from hvd.  :-)

Comment: @HostileFork Thank you, now at least I can use O3 optimization.